# How to add spacing between two radio buttons that are next to each other

Tags: php, html, css, radio-button, styling

I'm having difficulty adding spacing between two radio buttons that are next to each other. They are too close to each other for my liking and I feel that it would look a lot better if I added some spacing in between. I'm talking about the width, not the height of them.

I've tried added padding and margin. I'm not too sure how exactly to add spacing in between.

```
<div class="style" style="width 100px; float:left; height 100px; margin:0px;">
<!-- this code asks the suer what clothing style they like. They have a lot of options. The code is like the gender code -->
Select a style: <br /> 
<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Casual" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Casual') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Casual</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Athletic" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Athletic') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Athletic</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Vintage" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Vintage') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Vintage</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Formal" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Formal') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Formal</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Streetwear" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Streetwear') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Streetwear</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Rocker" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['style'] == 'Rocker') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Rocker</label>
</div>


<?php
if(($_POST['size'] == NULL) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
    echo "<strong>Please select a clothing size!</strong><br />";
}
?>

<div class="size" style="width 100px; float:left; height 100px; margin:0px;">
Select a size: <br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Small" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Extra Small') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Extra Small</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Small') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Small</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="style" value="Medium" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Medium') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Medium</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Large</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="Extra Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == 'Extra Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>Extra Large</label><br />

<label> <input type="radio" name="size" value="2X Large" 
<?php 
if ($_POST['size'] == '2X Large') {
        echo "checked";
}
?>
/>2X Large</label>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to add spacing in between the two radio buttons so they are not super close to each other. I have not added any css to the div classes. Here is what it looks like now: [mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyeZw.png)

Comment: Please only include the code that is necessary for us to solve your problem

Comment: where are you adding padding/margin to the radio buttons? This isn't in your code.

Comment: use  `&nbsp;` for a non-breaking space, or CSS margins ...  `style="margin-left: 10px"` don't style with text formatting.  That is what CSS is for.

Comment: you want to add space between **radio buttons** vertically or between **div**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply `margin-right: 50px;` (change the value to fit what you need) on your first div like

```
<div class="style" style="width 100px; float:left; height 100px; margin-right: 50px;">
```